# Delete current minor version of a SharePoint Page

Tags: events, sharepoint

In the SharePoint page library on an event handler I want to delete the current minor version of the page.

Let's assume that my current version is 3.15 and I want to delete this version. I am using the item.File.Versions.DeleteByLabel by throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the specific error, my guess would be that you would need to restore an old version before you are able to delete the version where [SPFileVersion.IsCurrentVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfileversion.iscurrentversion.aspx) is true.

Edit:

Your comments confirm what I suspected, you cannot delete the current version. As I looked into it more, it appears that the current version might not even be present in the SPFileVersionCollection. The code in your second comment might not take any action. You can verify this by trying the following:

```
if (null == item.File.Versions.GetVersionFromLabel("3.15")) {
    // current version isn't contained in SPFileVersionCollection
}
```

As I think about your problem more, do you really want to delete the current version or do you want to rollback to the previous version? If that latter is the case, could you use [SPFile.UndoCheckOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.undocheckout.aspx) instead?

Comment: Rich thanks for your reply. When i debug it throws an SPException and the error code " Cannot delete the current version -2146232832"

Comment: My code:

 SPListItemVersionCollection coll = item.Versions;
 foreach (SPListItemVersion version in coll)
 {
   if (version.IsCurrentVersion)
   {
    version.Delete();
   }
 }

Comment: I want to restore file  to previous version instead of deleting. I have replaced version.Delete with file.UndoCheckout I still get error code with Cannot delete the current version.

Comment: I'd suggest updating your question with your most recent code. It's difficult to determine the problem from comments. Especially since, according to the MSDN page for SPFile.UndoCheckOut, "Cannot delete the current version" is not list as an error for UndoCheckOut.

Comment: Here is my code:                                                     SPFile file = item.File;
SPListItemVersionCollection coll = item.Versions;
foreach (SPListItemVersion version in coll)
{
  if (version.IsCurrentVersion)
  {
    file.UndoCheckOut();
  }
}

Comment: What happens if you try: SPFile file = item.File; file.UndoCheckOut();

Comment: I tried using UndoCheckOut but doesn't restore back to older version but when I use file.CheckIn("check in", SPCheckinType.OverwriteCheckIn); it restores it to older version.